# content of one file conent into another in windows using command prompt without specifying adject destination file name like abc*.txt

Tags: windows, cmd

how to write content of one file content into another in windows using command prompt (if destination file like abc*.txt ) without specifying adject destination file name .
Destination file name is a manner like abc12.txt, abc_13.txt .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i have to override the content of a file name abc_*.properties from a file abc (both files are at same location)